# Does the Jol-Nar promissory note allow the recipient to research faction technology unit upgrades?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

The promissory note for the Jol-Nar in [twilight-imperium](/questions/tagged/twilight-imperium) (4th ed) reads as:

> After the Jol-Nar player researches a technology that is not a faction technology:
>
> Gain that technology.
>
> Then, return this card to the Jol-Nar player.

Many races have faction technologies that happen to be unit upgrades, e.g. Sol's carriers/infantry, Saar's space docks etc.

Let's say that one of these factions has Jol-Nar's promissory note. The Jol-Nar research a unit upgrade. Can the holder of the promissory note gain their faction version of that upgrade?

---

Note, the game that inspired this had Muaat swap their promissory note with Jol-Nar's. The Muaat note says:

> Action: Remove 1 token from the Muaat player's fleet pool and return it to his reinforcements. Then, gain your war sun unit upgrade technology card. Then, return this card to the Muaat player.

The idea being that Jol-Nar gains War Suns the easy way, and Muaat gains Prototype War Sun II too.

Comment: Are you asking whether the card that specifically says "not a faction technology" works on something that is a faction technology?

Comment: @bwarmer: Yes. If Jol-Nar researches Fighter 2, does Naalu get their faction specific fighters? Or if Jol-Nar researches Infantry 2, does Arborec get Latani Warrior 2 or Sol get Spec Ops 2? Etc.

Comment: @bwarner: Just to mention, Jol-Nar doesn't have any unit upgrade faction technologies (they have access to the regular unit upgrade techs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The card says "Gain that technology". It does not allow gaining your faction specific variant of that technology. Effectively, this means that you cannot use the card in that situation (or if you did, it would not get you any benefit).

I don't have an official ruling to back this up, but a literal reading of the card text seems pretty clear. [This thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2011206/jolnars-pn-research-agreement-and-faction-unit-upg) on BGG agrees.